# XML Parsing with same tag

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

I need to get

1. "Enter User Name", "Enter Password"
2. "stack@gmail.com" / "abcd*"

in separate lists

```
<steps id="0" last="3">
  <step id="1" type="ValidateStep">
    <parameterizedString><text>Enter User Name</text></parameterizedString>
    <parameterizedString><text>stack@gmail.com</text></parameterizedString>
    <description>
    </description>
  </step>
  <step id="2" type="ValidateStep">
    <parameterizedString><text>EnterPassword</text> </parameterizedString>
    <parameterizedString><text>abcd*</text></parameterizedString>
    <description></description></step>
  <step id="3" type="ActionStep">
    <parameterizedString>
    <text>Click on Login Button</text>
    </parameterizedString><parameterizedString />
    <description />
  </step>
</steps>
```

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlSteps);
var values = (from f in doc.Elements().Descendants()
              select f.Attribute("text").Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I need to get stack@gmail.com and abcd* into a list.

Comment: is it always `step` with `id="1"` that you want?

Comment: I need  all the paramenterzied string

Comment: so you want "Enter User Name" and "EnterPassword" in one list and "stack@gmail.com" and "abcd*" in one list? or do you want them all in one list? what have you tried? why is that not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want this for step 1 & 2 only (otherwise remove the line with comment), use something similar to this:

```
var values = doc.Descendants("step")
            .Where(step => new[] { "1", "2" }.Contains(step.Attribute("id").Value)) //only step 1 & 2
            .Select(step => step.Descendants("text").Select(text => text.Value).ToList());
```